# replace cells with tuple

Tags: python, pandas

How would I get a tuple consisting of both the index element and the current element itself:

With the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 'y', None], [None, None, 'x'], ['z', None, None]],
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                  columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
print(f'\n{df.to_string()}')
```

I get:

```
      X     Y     Z
a  None     y  None
b  None  None     x
c     z  None  None
```

What I would like is the following:

```
      X     Y     Z
a  None  (a,y)  None
b  None  None  (b,x)
c  (c,z) None  None
```

A rather crude attempt to solve this results in an error about `.name`:

```
df2 = df.mask(pd.isnull, lambda x: (x,x.name))
print(f'\n{df2.to_string()}')
```

Comment: Please post the problem code -- I don't see your attempt here.  This is simply making a tuple of the row index and the existing value, no?

Comment: @Prune - I've modified the question to show an attempt.. can't seem to combine both the index and the current cell as you alluded to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `df.agg` and `zip` and dataframe slicing

```
df.agg(lambda x: list(zip(df.index, x)))[df.notna()]

Out[928]:
        X       Y       Z
a     NaN  (a, y)     NaN
b     NaN     NaN  (b, x)
c  (c, z)     NaN     NaN
```

---

**Note**: I think `NaN` representation is better than `None`, so I keep it as `NaN`

Comment: Upvoted; this is how you make the list I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Andy - it took a bit to grok what you were doing there. TIL.